# Java Dynamic Type How To?

Tags: java, android

```
import org.json.*;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * Created by nubuntu on 10/06/2015.
 */
public class Object {
    private Callback callback;
    static void each(JSONObject json,Callback callback){
        Iterator<?> keys = json.keys();
        while( keys.hasNext() ) {
            String key = (String)keys.next();
            try {
                callback.run(key,json.get(key));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    static void each(JSONArray json,Callback callback){
        for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++){
            JSONObject obj = null;
            try {
                obj = json.getJSONObject(i);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            callback.run(obj);
        }
    }
    public interface Callback{
        public void run(String key, java.lang.Object o);
    }
    // Error : Duplicate Class
    public interface Callback{
        public void run(java.lang.Object o);
    }

}
```

I want to implement "each" like jquery for JSONObject & JSONArray, maybe many other object later,
example of use:

```
        JSONObject jsonobject= new JSONObject("hair":"black","eye":"blue");
        Object.each(jsonobject,new Object.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void run(String key, Object o) {
                Log.d(key,o.toString());
            }
        });
```

but when I want create second Callback, it can not duplicate like above static each method, 
so how to handle each for dynamic type??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of android, I think your code will work if you change as below:

```
 public interface Callback{
    public void run(String key, java.lang.Object o);
    public void run(java.lang.Object o);
}
```

your `each` function got errors because of your `Callback` interface not because of itself.

Answer (score 0):

It should be different names for different interfaces.

```
public interface CallbackKeyValue {
    public void run(String key, java.lang.Object o);
}

public interface CallbackValue {
    public void run(java.lang.Object o);
}
```

Lambda expression in JAVA8 does not require any interface names.

```
Object.each(jsonobject, (key, o) ->
    Log.d(key, o.toString())
);
```

Comment: See [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).  There are standard interfaces you wont.  `BiConsumer<String, Object>` and `Consumer<Object>`

Answer (score 0):

wow, how can I miss this simply solution, thanks @Kingfisher

but now, how to avoid other useless "run" method, callback just need one run method to execute

```
        JSONObject jsonobject= new JSONObject("{'hair':'black','eye':'blue'}");
        Object.each(jsonobject, new Object.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void run(String key, java.lang.Object o) {
                // Code run here....
            }

            @Override
            public void run(java.lang.Object o) {
                // useless
            }
        });
```